# Not able to download SVG as PNG in IE

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, svg, png

I created a chart in d3. According to my requirement, I have to allow for downloading as PNG in all browsers. I am using saveSvgAsPng.js for that.

```
saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("sample"), "sample.png", { width: '50%' });
```

I am able to download it in Chrome and Firefox, but I am not able to download in IE.

On checking console, I get below errors:

> Unknown font format for https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla;
>   Fonts may not be working correctly
>
> Rendered SVG images cannot be downloaded in this browser.

I do not know if I missed any parameters to pass in.

Comment: Could be this? `Internet Explorer will only work if canvg is passed in, otherwise it will throw a SecurityError when calling toDataURL on a canvas that's been written to.` from [saveSvgAsPng](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng#support)

Comment: any idea how to send canvg??

Answer (score 1):

As per [saveSvgAsPng GitHub](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng#support)

> Internet Explorer will only work if [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) is passed in, otherwise it will throw a SecurityError when calling toDataURL on a canvas that's been written to. [...]

So you must include your script canvg and then pass it as a parameter

```
var svg = document.querySelector('sample');
saveSvgAsPng(svg, "sample.png", {canvg:window.canvg});
```